# Generate a matrix where entries are non-zero and determinant is non-zero

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm thinking about this: generating a $n\times n$ square matrix, whose entries are all non-zero, and the determinant is significantly different from zero.

Suppose the matrix is $A$. I tried the following methods:

Let $A_{ij} = (i-1)n+j$. Well this is apparently wrong after $n$ is larger than 3. The determinants would become zero.

I then tried replacing $A_{ij}$ with $(A_{ij})^{1/2}$, but the determinant becomes a very small number.

As $n$ becomes very large, how can we still make sure the absolute value of determinant is not too small?

Comment: If you can find $A$ with $\mathrm{det}(A)\neq0,$ then $c\cdot A$ will have determinant $c^{n}\mathrm{det}(A)$, where $n$ is the order of the matrix. If you want all entries to have the same magnitude, check out [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix)

Comment: Two quick thoughts. First, random entries will be nonzero as will the determinant. Second, start from a diagonal matrix $D$ with large values. Then most matrices $UDU^{-1}$ will have nonzero entries.

Comment: You could use a Vandermonde matrix, it has a nice easy form and determinant.

Comment: You could use the Hilbert-Matrix, which has a 'not too small' determinant. // Or since $\det(A) = \prod λ_i$, $λ_i$ eigenvalues, you can use [Gershgorin Circle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to construct matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Householder matrix of the form $$Q = I - vv^T.$$
Here $I$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n$ and $v$ is a random vector which has been scaled such that $v^Tv = 2$. This choice ensure that $Q$ is orthogonal, i.e. $Q^TQ = I$. It follows that the determinant of $Q$ is $\pm 1$.

Observe, that if all components of $v$ are nonzero, then the off diagonal entries of $Q$ are nonzero, specifically $q_{ij} = - v_iv_j$. The diagonal entries are $q_{ii} = 1 - v_i^2$, so avoid $v_i = \pm 1$.

This construction gives you a well conditioned test matrix with a trivial inverse.

Answer (score 2):

How about the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1& \dots& 1 \\1& 2 & 1 &\dots& 1\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&1&1&\dots&2\end{bmatrix}$$
i.e. $A=[1,\dots 1]\cdot[1\dots1]^T + I$?

The determinant of $A$ is, I think, $n+1$ (i.e., $1$ more than the size of $A$), so it actually becomes larger as $n$ increases.

Comment: The determinant is indeed $n+1$: $$\det (\mathrm I_n + 1_n 1_n^\top) = \det (1 + 1_n^\top 1_n) = 1+n$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the matrix

\begin{equation}
  A = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
    t & t & t & \cdots & t & t \\
    1 & 2 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 2 & & 1 & 1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots\\ 
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 2
  \end{pmatrix}
  \,,
\end{equation}
which has determinant $t$.

To show that the matrix has determinant $t$, start with the matrix
$[t e_1 | e_2 | \cdots | e_n]$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th unit vector. We have
$$
    \det [t e_1 | e_2 | \cdots | e_n] = t
    \,.
$$
The determinant is multilinear, giving that
$$
t
= \det [t e_1 | e_2 | \cdots | e_n]
= \det [t e_1 + e_2 | e_2 | \cdots | e_n]
= \cdots
= \det [t e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_n | e_2 | \cdots | e_n]
\,.
$$
If we define $v = t e_1 + e_2 + \cdots + e_n$, then
$$
t 
= \det[t v | e_2 | \cdots | e_n] 
= \det[t v | e_2 + v | \cdots | e_n + v] \,,
$$
where we used the multilinearity of the determinant, again. The matrix $[t v | e_2 + v | \cdots | e_n + v]$ is equal to $A$.

In general, starting with a diagonal matrix and using the multilinearity can be used to construct various matrices with prescribed determinant.